# Diskless with Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: 12.04, boot, nfs, initramfs, pxe

I'm trying to setup a new diskless solution with ubuntu 12.04 without any success.  I followed this [Diskless Ubuntu HowTo](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/DisklessUbuntuHowto)

But the initramfs seems not to be able to mount my nfs share.

On my server side:

My /etc/exports

```
/srv/nfs4           192.168.0.0/24(fsid=0,rw,no_subtree_check)

/srv/nfs4/nfsroot   192.168.0.0/24(rw,no_root_squash,no_subtree_check,fsid=1,nohide,insecure,sync)
```

I'm able to mount my nfs share on standard Ubuntu installation without any problem.

I can mount my nfs on any client with those commands:

```
mount 192.168.0.3:/nfsroot /mnt
```

or

```
mount 192.168.0.3:/srv/nfs4/nfsroot /mnt
```

My /tftpboot/pxelinux.cfg/default config file is

```
DEFAULT vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic nfsroot=192.168.0.3:/nfsroot ip=dhcp rw
```

I also tried

```
DEFAULT vmlinuz-3.5.0-25-generic root=/dev/nfs initrd=initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic nfsroot=192.168.0.3:/srv/nfs4/nfsroot ip=dhcp rw.
```

**What I got in initramfs:**

With the setting [nfsroot=192.168.0.3:/nfsroot]

Diskless output:

```
mount call failed - server replied: Permission denied
```

On Syslog of my nfs server:

```
rpc.mountd[1266]: refused mount request from 192.168.0.10 for /nfsroot (/): not exported
```

With the setting [nfsroot=192.168.0.3:/srv/nfs4/nfsroot]

Diskless output:

```
mount: the kernel lacks NFS v3 support
```

On Syslog of my nfs server I got:

```
Mar 11 14:03:06 BootFromLan rpc.mountd[1266]: authenticated mount request from 192.168.0.10:834 for /srv/nfs4/nfsroot (/srv/nfs4/nfsroot)
Mar 11 14:03:06 BootFromLan rpc.mountd[1266]: refused unmount request from 192.168.0.10 for /root (/): not exported
```

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt seems to be wrong because the full path is not specified.

Your second attempt seems to be that there is a mismatch in nfs versions: The initramfs loads version 4 but the server only serves version 3.

Probably this might help:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/SettingUpNFSHowTo

You might try to compile the TFTP-Served kernel with nfs-3-support, see `lsinitramfs initrd.img-3.5.0-25-generic` to check what's inside.

Comment: But when I try to mount my nfs share remotely I can mount with nfs V4: mount -t nfs4 192.168.0.3:/nfsroot /mnt.

Comment: And when I list my mount, I can see: 192.168.0.3:/nfsroot on /mnt type nfs4 (rw,addr=192.168.0.3,clientaddr=192.168.0.2)

Comment: Yes, since the module is not present in the initramfs. Perhapse replace `root=/dev/nfs` with `rootfstype=nfs4 root=/dev/nfs4`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe issue with the files, did you use `cp -ax` to copy the files from the DVD/image to NFS. See http://ubuntuforums.org/archive/index.php/t-921313.html

Or, it will automatically unmount the given NFS share when it doesn't find the kernel stuff it is looking for.

You might need the **boot=casper** or similiar. Check your NFS directory structure. `dirname find /nfs -type f -name "*linuz*"`